# Unable to Run Training (Models) in Tensorflow 2.1.0 and Python 2.7.17 Using faster_rcnn_inception_v2_coco_2018_01_28

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, object-detection

I am facing issue while trying to run below command:-

```
**python train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=training/ --pipeline_config_path=training/faster_rcnn_inception_v2_pets.config**
```

On this setting:

```
Tensorflow Version:- 2.1.0
Python Version:- 2.7.17
OS :- Window10
```

Please find below mentioned error message:-

```
(tensorflow1) C:\tensorflow1\models\research\object_detection>python train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=training/ --pipeline_config_path=training/faster_rcnn_inception_v2_pets.config

2020-08-05 21:57:27.148584: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:59] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_101.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_101.dll not found

2020-08-05 21:57:27.160441: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.

WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\MuditKhare\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py:250: main (from main) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use object_detection/model_main.py.
W0805 21:57:33.450702 17004 deprecation.py:323] From C:\Users\MuditKhare\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py:250: main (from main) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use object_detection/model_main.py.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "train.py", line 188, in
tf.compat.v1.app.run()
File "C:\Users\MuditKhare\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 40, in run
_run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
File "C:\Users\MuditKhare\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 299, in run
_run_main(main, args)
File "C:\Users\MuditKhare\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 250, in _run_main
sys.exit(main(argv))
File "C:\Users\MuditKhare\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\deprecation.py", line 324, in new_func
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "train.py", line 183, in main
graph_hook_fn=graph_rewriter_fn)
File "C:\tensorflow1\models\research\object_detection\legacy\trainer.py", line 248, in train
detection_model = create_model_fn()
File "C:\tensorflow1\models\research\object_detection\builders\model_builder.py", line 1016, in build
add_summaries)
File "C:\tensorflow1\models\research\object_detection\builders\model_builder.py", line 553, in _build_faster_rcnn_model
_check_feature_extractor_exists(frcnn_config.feature_extractor.type)
File "C:\tensorflow1\models\research\object_detection\builders\model_builder.py", line 243, in _check_feature_extractor_exists
'Tensorflow'.format(feature_extractor_type))

**ValueError: faster_rcnn_inception_v2 is not supported. See model_builder.py for features extractors compatible with different versions of Tensorflow**
```

Please help me to fix this issue.

Thanks,
Mudit Khare